# How can i blacklist words in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to blacklist the words "unknown" and "reboot". How do i do that using regular expressions?

And i have a list of users that it matches but i want it to blacklist certain words like unknown and reboot whilst still matching names such as "15ppool" and "vici".

This is what my current expression looks like that i have tried:

```
 ^[a-z]+|\w{4,8}
```

Comment: Your current regex matches `[a-z]+` only if at `^` start of string `|` or `\w{4,8}` anywhere in the string. Is this meant? [In this demo](https://regex101.com/r/cU1oR5/1) using a neg. [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and only matching at `^` start.

Comment: I actually solved it by using this: \n(\w{1,9})\s+:0

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have to build a regex to match your desired format, just exclude those two terms:

```
while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    say unless /unknown|reboot/;
}

__DATA__
foo
15ppool
unknown
bar
vici
reboot
baz
```